# using modules cant get vpc_id from terraform_remote_state for use in other modules

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have two modules one a vpc and one for creating a security group.

I cant get the terraform_remote_state:

```
 vpc_id  = data.terraform_remote_state.network_configuration.outputs.vpc_id
```

In my IDE pycharm outputs does not exists i.e. like outputs is not a valid option

In the root I get the output like the below:

```
module "vpc" {
  source                = "./modules/vpc"
  region                = var.region
  vpc_cidr              = var.vpc_cidr
  public_subnet_1_cidr  = var.public_subnet_1_cidr
  public_subnet_2_cidr  = var.public_subnet_2_cidr
  public_subnet_3_cidr  = var.public_subnet_3_cidr
  private_subnet_1_cidr = var.private_subnet_1_cidr
  private_subnet_2_cidr = var.private_subnet_2_cidr
  private_subnet_3_cidr = var.private_subnet_3_cidr
}

output "vpc_id" {
  value = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

In the VPC module I have an outputs.tf with the below:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = aws_vpc.production-vpc.id
}
```

In the root directory I have outputs.ts with the below:

```
output "vpc_id" {
  value = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

below is my security groups module:

```
data "terraform_remote_state" "network_configuration" {
  backend = "s3"
  config = {
    bucket = var.remote_state_bucket
    key    = var.remote_state_key
    region = var.region
    profile = "terraform"
  }
}

resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_private_security_group" {
  name = "EC2-Private-SG"
  description = "Only allow public SG resoruces to access instances"
  vpc_id = data.terraform_remote_state.network_configuration.outputs.vpc_id
  ...
}
```

What am I doing wrong to get the vpc_id ?  I get the below error

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on modules/sg/sg.tf line 19, in resource "aws_security_group" "ec2_private_security_group":
  19:   vpc_id      = data.terraform_remote_state.network_configuration.outputs.vpc_id
    |----------------
    | data.terraform_remote_state.network_configuration.outputs is object with no attributes

This object does not have an attribute named "vpc_id".
```

Comment: Why are you using `terraform_remote_state` for passing your data around? Why not just pass vpc id as a regular input variable to your security group module?

Comment: I see now...yes that worked thanks...newbie with terraform

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comments.

Its not a good practice to use `terraform_remote_state` for passing variables between modules. Instead, you should pass variables to modules, as regular input variables:

```
 vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
```